# Assigning string to variable in conditional gives error

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to have a dynamic marker type for my scatter plot. So, I have something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(20,40,size=(5,1)))
y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(24,26,size=(5,1)))

if x <= 30:
marker_type = 'o' and fill_type = 'full' and label_type = "var <= 30"
if x > 30 and symbols_x <= 40:
marker_type = 'o' and fill_type = 'none' and label_type = "30 < var <= 40"

plot = plt.figure(1)
plt.scatter(x, y, marker=marker_type, fill=fill_type, label=label_type)
legend = plot.legend(loc='upper right')
plot.show()
```

But I get an error that shows: "SyntaxError: can't assign to operator"
Any solutions?

Comment: What are you trying to do? `scatter` does not have `fill`?

Comment: @QuangHoang i belive the `fill` should be `fillstyles`. This refers to the actual markers of the scatter plot

Comment: scatter also does not have a `fillstyles` argument. Possible arguments are listed in [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html).

Comment: I was looking for `facecolors` and `edgecolors` to get the desired effect. I think I was getting `fill` from Matlab.

Comment: Given that most of the code of the question as it stands does not make sense, maybe you want to update? Especially, you may comment on why not simply plot 2 scatters, one for values above and one for values below 30.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The linked document doesn't list either `fillstyle` or `fillstyles`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest sorry. I messed up the lines. Need my lunch.

Answer (score 0):

if you make you if loop as below, this error will disappear.

```
if x <= 30:
    marker_type = 'o' 
    fill_type = 'full' 
    label_type = "var <= 30"
else:
    pass
if x > 30 and symbols_x <= 40:
    marker_type = 'o' 
    fill_type = 'none' 
    label_type = "30 < var <= 40"
else:
    pass
```

However, you assigned a whole dataframe X to a Yes or No. So you will get the error as below.
"ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Comment: I see what you mean by assigning the whole dataframe, but even if i do something like x[0] (calling just one column), i still get the error

Comment: You cannot decide if a bunch of numbers is greater than a single number. (Just think about what would you expect from `if [1,2,5,6] > 3`? *Some* numbers are smaller, *some* are bigger.)

Comment: Yes, but I would like for the ones that _are_ bigger to be affected by the conditional. Surely there's some way to do that.